# How to execute a PostgreSQL stored procedure from PetaPoco (with Npgsql)?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, petapoco

Given a PostgreSQL (9.5) stored procedure (with Npgsql driver) as:

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GetAllDx"(
>       patient_recid integer,
>       tencounter timestamp without time zone)   RETURNS SETOF view_dx

How is this executed from PetaPoco ?  Can it be done? (I've been using Dapper).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple,

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetAllPatientsWithServices()
        {
            // Create a PetaPoco database object
            var db = new chaosDB("localconnection");

            // Calling stored procedure getallpatientswithservices()
            var a =  db.Fetch<view_patient>("Select * from getallpatientswithservices()");

            foreach( var b in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}    -  {1}", b.cpatient, b.chart_number);
            }
        }
```

Or, with a mixed-case procedure name:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetDxLibrary()
        {
            // Create a PetaPoco database object
            var db = new chaosDB("localconnection");

            // Calling stored procedure with mixed case name
            var a = db.Fetch<icd9>("Select * from \"GetDxLibrary\"()");

            foreach (var b in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}    -  {1}", b.code,b.cdesc);
            }
        }
```